# Requesting information about Amsterdam Travel Cards

Tags: public-transport, tickets, netherlands, amsterdam

I'm going to visit Amsterdam in last week of June and I'll stay near Sloterdijk Station.

I will land at 9pm in AMS and stay for 5 days.

I have done some search and found out there are three types of tickets for travellers.

- [Amsterdam Travel Ticket](https://www.ns.nl/producten/en/overige-kaartjes/p/amsterdam-travel-ticket)
- [Holland Travel Ticket](https://www.ns.nl/producten/en/alleen-te-koop-via-station-of-kaartautomaat/p/holland-travel-ticket)
- [Amsterdam and Region Travel Ticket](https://www.ns.nl/producten/en/alleen-te-koop-via-station-of-kaartautomaat/p/amsterdam-region-travel-ticket)

I planned to stay and visit places around Amsterdam only.

Since I land at night, I only need to travel to Sloterdijk Station. My questions are:

- What will be the best ticket for that? (Getting a train or bus?)
- Other days I need to travel around the city. What is the best way to travel using the train (NS) or bus/tram network (GVB)?
- Do I have value of purchasing one of the above tickets?
- As I understand Amsterdam Travel Ticket only include Train to travel from Airport to one station and has unlimited bus travelling for the period of the card mentioned. Am I correct?
- If I buy a train ticket via the mobile app, do I need to pay for the additional charge for a smart card (€1)? Do I need to print it or can the pass on the mobile's screen be scanned?

Comment: Depending on the exact date of your arrival, there will be no trains going at night between Schiphol and Sloterdijk because of roadwork. A replacement bus will be available. More info here: http://www.ns.nl/en/journeyplanner/#/?vertrek=Schiphol%20Airport&vertrektype=treinstation&aankomst=Amsterdam%20Sloterdijk&aankomsttype=treinstation&tijd=2017-06-19T16:24&type=vertrek

Comment: @JaneDoe1337 thank you very much for the info. Really valuable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have OV chip card and all tickets will add additional €1.00 to ticket price. So better to buy with return at once.

**Amsterdam Travel Ticket**

*Train*

With the Amsterdam Travel Ticket, you may travel by train (2nd class) between Schiphol Amsterdam Airport and any of the following stations in Amsterdam: Amstel, Bijlmer ArenA, Central Station, Holendrecht, Lelylaan, Muiderpoort, RAI, Sciencepark, Sloterdijk, Zuid, Duivendrecht.

*Tram, bus, metro, ferry*

The ticket is valid on all trams, buses, night buses, metros and ferries run by the Amsterdam transport company GVB. You can recognise them by their white and blue colours. GVB operates an extensive network covering the whole of Amsterdam. NOTE: The ticket is not valid on buses operated by other transport companies such as EBS, Arriva and Connexxion (except buses 197 and N97).

*Amsterdam Airport Express*

The ticket is valid on the Amsterdam Airport Express, bus 197 and Niteliner N97. Both are operated by Connexxion and depart from bus platform B9 at Schiphol Amsterdam Airport.

> 1-day (€ 16), 2-day (€ 21) and 3-day (€ 26)

**Amsterdam and Region Travel Ticket**

*Train*

You can use the Amsterdam Travel Ticket for unlimited travel by train (2nd class) between any of the following stations in Amsterdam and the Amsterdam region: Amsterdam Amstel, Amsterdam Bijlmer ArenA, Amsterdam Central Station, Amsterdam Holendrecht, Amsterdam Lelylaan, Amsterdam Muiderpoort, Amsterdam RAI, Amsterdam Sciencepark, Amsterdam Sloterdijk, Amsterdam Zuid, Duivendrecht, Schiphol Amsterdam Airport, Halfweg-Zwanenburg, Haarlem, Haarlem Spaarnwoude, Overveen, Zandvoort aan Zee, Zaandam, Zaandam Kogerveld, Purmerend Weidevenne, Purmerend, Purmerend Overwhere, Koog aan de Zaan, Zaandijk Zaanse Schans, Hoofddorp, Diemen, Weesp, Almere Poort, Almere Centrum, Almere Muziekwijk, Almere Parkwijk, Almere Buiten, Almere Oostvaarders, Lelystad Centrum, Diemen Zuid, Naarden-Bussum, Bussum Zuid, Hilversum, Hilversum Media Park and Hilversum Sportpark.

*Tram, bus, metro, ferry*

The ticket is valid on all trams, buses, night buses, metros and ferries run by the Amsterdam transport company GVB, EBS and Connexxion in Amsterdam and the Amsterdam region.

> 1-day (€ 18.50), 2-day (€ 26) and 3-day (€ 33.50)

**Holland Travel Ticket**

The Holland Travel Ticket gives you carefree and unlimited travel for one day throughout the Netherlands on all public transport.

> €59 per day

If you travel around Amsterdam Central better to get Amsterdam Travel card. If you travel around Amsterdam Region area then Get Amsterdam Regional Travel card. If you plan to visit other areas in same day get a holland travel card. If you only travel to Amsterdam Central and do walking just get a normal ticket.

Comment: If you plan on using separate tickets, consider buying an OV chip card. You pay once for the card, 7.50, but it is cheaper to use. You need €20 on it for the use of the trains, but only €4.50 for other transports. And there is a bus from Sloterdijk and from central Amsterdam to the airport. https://www.ov-chipkaart.nl/purchase-an-ov-chipkaart.htm

Comment: Drawback is need to have €20 to use trains

Answer (score 2):

You should calculate best costs yourself based on next facts:

1. 1-hour public transport ticket in Amsterdam is [2.90] and you can not use train within the city. [1](https://en.gvb.nl/gvb-1-uur)
2. For travelling around Amsterdam will use train and busses. For the train prices you can look [here](https://www.nsinternational.nl/en). Unfortunately, I don't know how you can get ticket price if you don't own ov card.
3. Cost for ov-card is 7.50 and prices can be locked [here](https://9292.nl/en). You can refund remaining costs on the card with fee 1 euro, but you can not return the card.

The trains within the city might be handy for since you will live close by to Sloterdijk.

Comment: Ticket prices for train tickets without an OV card are the same price as those with, but you will need to pay €1 extra for the paper ticket and €0.50 on top of that if you buy from a ticket window or pay with a credit card. Bus prices without an OV card are in the same range as those in Amsterdam, say roughly €3 for an hour short distances but going up for longer rides.

Comment: Thanks, I sometimes took the bus from Schiphol to Amstelveen and on my memory price was around 5 euro. But can not remember.

Comment: @EugenMartynov Exact price depends on which company is operating that bus, [€5 is indeed the price for a Connexxion bus outside towns](https://connexxion.nl/reizen/1190/maxx-reis/256).